# How to resize Ubuntu partition with unallocated space w/GParted & LiveCD

Tags: installation, unity, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I currently have one hard drive with 3 partitions and 2 partitions of unallocated space.  I am dual booting Windows 7 (1 partition) and another partition for Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm using Gparted and Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD with all drives unmounted, this is what i'm seeing:

1. /dev/sda1. NTFS.  325gb, 292gb used. Boot flag. = WINDOWS 7
2. (extended) /dev/sda2. EXTENDED. 92.95gb.  lba flag.

   2A. (extended) /dev/sda5.  EXT4.  89gb.  = UBUNTU
   2B. (under extended) unallocated. 3.82gb
3. unallocated. 39.75gb = ???
4. /dev/sda4. NTFS.  Respawn Recovery. 7.79gb. 4.27gb used.
5. unallocated. 3.02mb.

I CAN resize sda4 to include the 40gb of unallocated space but obviously I dont see the point in doing that to a recovery partition. 
I CAN resize sda5 to include the unallocated space of 3.82gb but would this help?

Help?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can increase the size of  **sda2** (Extended Partition) to the right, taking unallocated 39.75gb in it.
2. You can then increase the size of **sda5** (Logical Partition inside Extended Partition) to the right, taking unallocated 39.75gb in it.
3. You can also increase the size of **sda4** to the right, taking unallocated 3.02mb space in it.

The best way to do these is probably using **GParted** from a live Ubuntu CD/DVD/USB.